# Crear un nodo en Firebase Database con Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Puedo crear un nuevo nodo a partir de una existente en la base de datos de Firebase? Bueno, he usado HashMap para crear un nuevo nodo, pero solo toma el último hijo y no todos.

```
  DatabaseReference facturas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("XXX").child(Cabecera_listado_productos);

                                final HashMap<String, Object> td = new HashMap<>();

                                td.put("Plato", plato);
                                td.put("Precio",precio);
                                td.put("Cantidad", cantidad);
                                td.put("Precio_Total",p_total);

                                facturas.child(plato).updateChildren(td);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @cristian, aqui hay una respuesta, creo es lo que buscas https://stackoverflow.com/a/50501652 , recibe como parametros las dos rutas origen y destino, saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Wilmer por redireccionarme a ese enlace me quitaste un peso de encima.